# Interference from Graphics Card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, graphics

I have been using Ubuntu for a while now and have always had an issue with interference. It seems that the Graphics Driver I am using affects when the interference occurs and how loud it is. If I used the nouveau driver the interference is terrible and I get both hardware and audio interference. A loud high pitch squeal comes from my Graphics Card as well as interference down my headset.
People on Skype have said they can hear it as well.
However this problem does not occur when using windows and so it leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the drivers, but i have tried many different versions of Ubuntu and even Fedora and still had the same problem. I have changed graphics drivers but have not managed to get rid of this interference.
It is nothing to do with the hardware placement as it does not happen in Windows.
What is going on?

The Interference often occurs when loading things at high frame rate such as the start of games and so this makes me think it is the graphics card, but why does it only happen in Linux and not Windows?
I am using an Nvidia GTX 285 with proprietary driver.

Comment: Have you tried setting on Vsync in compizconfig?

Comment: I have, it doesnt seem to help :( i have been having troubles with Ubuntu and am using windows unfortunately, i will install when 13.10 comes out i think. Thankyou though :)